# How to make iTerm2 appear on the current space?

Tags: macos, iterm2, macos-high-sierra

in the preferences I set under `Profiles >  Window > Space` it to `current space` but it will open still open on space2.
It is really annoying that every time the space is changing bevor I can use iTerm.

Best

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When iTerm2 is running, right-click or Control-click on its icon in the Dock. From the Options submenu, under the Assign To label, select your preferred behavior. If you set it to None, it should open on whatever space is current when you launch it. iTerm2's preferences will probably take effect for this case. If you set it to All Desktops, it will be visible on all spaces. The other choices will force it to a specific space and that would probably override the preference within iTerm2.

Also, you can manually move individual windows of an app to another space by dragging it off the relevant edge of the desktop or within Mission Control.

Comment: Hi,
thanks. I had it to None Desktops and changed it to All Desktops that works.

Answer (score 2):

Set iTerm so that it shows up in the Dock. Now right-click the iTerm icon in the dock. Select Options and then select All Desktops. Now whatever space you are currently in will be where iterm displays.